# Redirection for wordpress network site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

when i open 
       http://subdomain.maindomain.com 
i need it automatically redirect to  http://subdomain.maindomain.com/wp-admin.

Please help me how can i achieve this.
I tried below code in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain.maindomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.maindomain.com/wp-admin/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: What exactly is not working ?

Comment: @starkeen i don't want to open main page , i need directly redirection on wp-admin page

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.maindomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.maindomain.com/wp-admin/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It's added an extra wp-admin?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Remove that code from .htaccess file and edit your subdomain's index.php file with this line.
`<?php wp_redirect(site_url('wp-admin'));`

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/

Use this plugin

Go to the page and then set redirect. It will redirect your wordpress page to your desired page. Hope that helps.